# How specify to [datetime]/Get-Date, that a date and time string is a british style and not an American style date?

Tags: powershell

Looking at the documentation for `Get-Date`, there does not appear to be any example on how to indicate to either `Get-Date` or the `[datetime]` type on how to interpret a date and time string that it will convert to a `[datetime]` object.

There are several example on how to do the reverse, that is how `Get-Date` should stringify a `[datetime]` object:

- [Example 3: Get the date and time with a .NET format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.3#example-3-get-the-date-and-time-with-a-net-format-specifier)
- [Example 4: Get the date and time with a UFormat specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-get-the-date-and-time-with-a-uformat-specifier)

I have a stringy that is giving me trouble, casting it to `[datetime]` throws an, as it seems to be expecting `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
 [datetime] "28/05/2023 15:05:29"
```

It throws an Error:

```
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "28/05/2023 15:05:29" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

It works with `get-date`:

```
get-date "28/05/2023 15:05:29"

28 May 2023 15:05:29
```

I have been dealing with this issue for some time now, and today is one more day wasted on error handling this issue.  I would like to know for once, is it possible to specify to both `Get-Date` and `[datetime]` how it should interpret the input string?

Searching around, I keep getting answers/articles on how to specify the date format for when stringifying a `[datetime]` object. Thank you

Comment: weird that `Get-Date` works for you but `[datetime]` doesn't, for me nor of them work and I'm using en-US culture. What do you get from `(Get-Culture).Name` ? You need to use `[datetime]::ParseExact` in this case to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.ParseExact` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-8.0) if you want to specify a format to parse your string:

```bash
[datetime]::ParseExact(
    '28/05/2023 15:05:29',
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Or, you can use the [`.Parse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-8.0) specifying a culture that uses `dd/MM/yyyy` as its default, for example Great Britain:

```bash
[datetime]::Parse(
    '28/05/2023 15:05:29',
    [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-GB'))
```

`Get-Date` doesn't offer such parsing capability, it depends entirely on your thread's [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-8.0), as an example (in my case using `en-US` culture):

```bash
Get-Date '28/05/2023 15:05:29'
# Get-Date: Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "28/05/2023 15:05:29" to type "System.DateTime".
# Error: "String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

& {
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-GB')
    Get-Date '28/05/2023 15:05:29'
    # Outputs: Sunday, 28 May 2023 15:05:29
}
```